# How to remove an index from a multiindex in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas multiindex and I would like to remove one of the index, how can I do that ?

The index to be removed is: `('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT',       'BTT',   'sp')`

```
MultiIndex([('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT',       'BTT', 'fut'),
            ('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT',       'BTT',   'sp'),
            ('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT', 'BT5', 'fut')],
           names=['code1', 'source', 'type', 'code2', 'destination', 'type'])
```

The desired output is this :

```
MultiIndex([('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT',       'BTT', 'fut'),
            ('B', 'BT', 'spot', 'BT', 'BT5', 'fut')],
           names=['code1', 'source', 'type', 'code2', 'destination', 'type'])
```

If the multiindex was a list I would do:

```
if indexes[1] in indexes: indexes.remove(indexes[1])
```

Comment: `indexes.drop(indexes[1])`

Comment: if you have a dataframe : `df.droplevel(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Mustapha Aydın in the comment section this is the best answer:

```
indexes.drop(indexes[1])
```